# ASP.NET Requests Queued causes website to crumble. SQL backend, IIS6

Tags: asp.net, sql, iis-6

I have inherited a somewhat complex system (and problem) that I need help with.

I have a webserver w/ the following specs:

- Hardware:

  - Server 2003 32bit
  - IIS 6
  - 8 cores (16 w/ hyperthreading)
  - 12gb RAM
  - ASP.NET site
  - 3 app pools, so 3 instances of w3wp.exe running.

This system serves a large number of people and bandwidth is fairly constant during business hours reaching ~ 68,000kbit/s

There are moments when the system "comes down" - site gets very slow which generates a lot of phone calls. Things usually slow down for 60 seconds, but has varied greatly in length. Sometimes only a few seconds and sometimes 3 minutes or more.

I have my app pools set to recycle somewhere about 600mb of consumed memory. That's not exact but they recycle on their own with much success. At times I recycle the "main" pool manually to clear the problem I'm describing.

This is what I know is going on when things are running slow.

- Network bandwidth takes a considerable dip.
- Requests Queued in the ASP.NET performance counters goes up.
- In tandem w/ the Requests Queued rising page latency increases. (I employ a simple ASP page that makes a SQL call and just says "The system is live" - this page is monitored for latency)
- Overall CPU usage rises.
- Overall memory consumption of w3wp.exe rises.

In my mind here is what I imagine is happening.

Someone asks the system to generate a report or glob of data. This spins up a process that consumes a large number of threads (ie, all available threads) This causes all other requests to the system to wait in the ASP.NET que pool which essentially kills the site. The lack of activity causes the network traffic to dip.

I have read many articles about thread queues, thread pools, etc. This is a good example: http://williablog.net/williablog/post/2008/12/02/Increase-ASPNET-Scalability-Instantly.aspx and does what I believe is a clue to help me solve my problem... but I'm not sure. My "Machine.config" file for the version of asp.net that I am using does not specify any of the thread values listed in the article so we are default for everything which I believe is incorrect given our situation.

If you were me; What would you do next? Where do you think the problem is?

edit: Here is a screenshot. It should be obvious when the problem is happening. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1St0T.png

edit:

I want to change these values for our setup. A few questions first:

1) After making the changes, what needs to be restarted for them to take effect?

2) How do these settings look for a system with 8 physical cores?

```
maxconnection = 96
maxIoThreads = 100
maxWorkerThreads = 100
minFreeThreads = 704 
minLocalRequestFreeThreads = 608
```

Comment: I'd nerf the 32-bit version of Windows, and go for the 64-bit. While 64-bit means code can consume more memory than 32-bit, it also means the machine can do twice the amount of work in a single cycle that a 32-bit OS can. It'll also give your apps more space, as even though you have 12 GB of ram, an app can only address 4 GB of it because it's a 32-bit program (and thus not aware of the PAE).

Comment: We will be going to 2008R2 / IIS7 - In the mean time, we need to understand what  the problem is, not abandon it and do something else.

Comment: We have that problem too,our server is going slow on 6000 web service\current connections, but at same time we have another separate server with iis 7 for static files (without asp) witch services 7000 connections without problems

Answer (score 2):

Not fun.

Many root causes share common symptoms which makes it difficult to diagnose without getting dirty with the application.  :) Pardon if some of these steps were implied.

Some next steps might be:

- Review the IIS logs of each site looking for things like:

  - HTTP response codes (5xx,4xx,3xx)
  - Request response times
- Review Windows Event Logs

  - How often are application pools cycling?
  - Application errors, etc.
- Verify processModel settings as suggested by @vinayc to make sure predecessor didn't get 'tricky'
- Install [DebugDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24370), its a surprisingly good tool for some basic analysis of memory and crash related problems.

  - This can also help you capture memory snaps to diagnose later.
  - Tess Ferrandez [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/) can help make heads/tails of memory snap analysis.
- Understand how many web applications are running in each AppPool.
- Investigate using a 'web garden' to possibly help minimize number of users impacted by 'slow down'
- Is a virus scanner enabled?  Is it running?  If so, verify exclusions.
- Are application teams available to help troubleshoot?  Identify if they have any custom application instrumentation that might help diagnose problem.

Is the behavior 'new'?  Or has it always been there?  If 'new', can you track down which deployment might have caused the new behavior?

Could the the description given of the 'slow down' behavior be attributed to an apppool recycle and resulting jitting of the application again? ala - the first request syndrome.

Reviewing the logs helps understand how the sites/applications are being used, which can be especially important if you don't own the codebase.  [Logparser](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24659) is an excellent tool for doing some IIS log analysis (as well as other formats).

Good luck!

Z

Comment: I'd _definitely_ review the site logs: is there something that causes the slowdown, or is it something that builds up over time?

Comment: Jeremy: It is something that causes it. The app pools are set to recycle @ 600mb virtual memory and that seems to keep things pretty healthy. 

What would you look for in the site logs?

Answer (score 1):

The settings that your are talking are part of [processModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w2sway1.aspx) element under `system.web` element from machine.config. For IIS6, following are applicable:

> ```
> autoConfig
> maxIoThreads
> maxWorkerThreads
> minIoThreads
> minWorkerThreads
> requestQueueLimit
> responseDeadlockInterval
> ```

Typically, you will only find `autoConfig="true"` and not other elements. Auto-config sets the values as per your machine configuration - the tuning is done as per recommended values (see *Threading Explained* section from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998549) article) which are same as sighted by the link that you have provided.
The [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998549) although dated, i excellent resource if you want to tune up these settings manually.

On the other hand, at the load that you are serving, I would recommend two things (if you haven't tried already)

- Use output caching aggressively - even if the data is dynamic, caching for say 30-60 seconds can give a definite boost at your load
- If you suspect certain requests are hogging too many threads then attempt to move those resources under different app-pool (you can use different web-site with different sub-domain or you can use different virtual directory/application and choose different app-pool)

Comment: I want to change these values for our setup. A few questions first: 

1) After making the changes, what needs to be restarted for them to take effect?   

2) How do these settings look for a system with 8 physical cores?

    maxconnection = 96
    maxIoThreads = 100
    maxWorkerThreads = 100
    minFreeThreads = 704 
    minLocalRequestFreeThreads = 608

Comment: @AaronJAnderson, 1) processModel change does not take effect till worker process is restarted (see remarks in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w2sway1%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). 2) Yes, those would be recommended values but if you have autoconfig="true" then you already have those values tuned for you!

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. We are fast tracking to 2008 R2 w/ IIS 7.5 and an aggressive external caching system.